# MySql Entity Framework error when using SaveChangesAsync ASP.NET Core

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm gettting an error when I try to use SaveChangesAsync with MySql EntityFramewok in a ASP.NET Core environment in dev mode in VS Code. Everything else works fine. No problems when using SaveChanges() either, without the async. Wonder if anyone else has this issue.

The error looks like this:

InvalidOperationException: Connection must be valid and open to commit transaction
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction.Commit()

The piece of code in the controller looks like this:

```
[HttpPut("/api/strategy/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateStrategy(int id, [FromBody] StrategyResource newStrategy)
{
  if(!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);

   mapper.Map<StrategyResource, Strategy>(newStrategy, strategyInDb );

   context.SaveChanges();              // works fine
   //await context.SaveChangesAsync();   gives ERROR

   var res = mapper.Map<Strategy, StrategyResource>(strategyInDb );
   return Ok(res);
}
```

Context initialization in the constructor of the controller (nothing special really)

```
    private readonly JTradeContext context;        
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public TradesController(JTradeContext context, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.context = context;
    }
```

Context is initially added to services int the start up class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddDbContext<JTradeContext>();
}
```

And finally the context class itself

```
public class JTradeContext:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Trade> Trades { get; set; }
    public DbSet<WebClient> WebClients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Strategy> Strategies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Portfolio> Portfolios { get; set; }


    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
       optionsBuilder.UseMySQL("my connection string here");
    }
}
```

Comment: How is context initialized?

Comment: Nothing special, as usual in the constructor. I updated the question to clarify this if that might help.